# Error in both numerical methods in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

Computed in Mathematica to obtain which method is efficient using residuals: [image]
Please what am I doing wrong because it not giving any output?

````
  y[t], {t, 0, 0.5}, Method -> Fehlberg45]```

```s9 = NDSolve[{y'[t] == -100 y[t] - 99 Exp[2 t], y[0] == 0}, 
  y, {t, 0, 0.5}, Method -> CRK4]```

    ```sys = {D[Y[t], t] == -100 Y[t] - 99 Exp[2 t]};
    residuals = sys /. Equal -> Subtract;
    LogPlot[Join[Abs[residuals /. s2], Abs[residuals /. s9]] // 
    Evaluate, {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Directive[Dashed, Green]},
    PlotLegends -> {"CRK4", "Fehlberg45"}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]```
````

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Please include definitions for `s2` and `s9`.

Comment: To second @Syed comment, what you have included here is only the definition of equations, and it's missing the actual solution where you used `NDSolve` I assume?

Comment: @MathX. It is been edited and can be viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is incomplete. A lot of your code is missing, I didn't see your method's definitions so I found them from the documentations.
Change them if you are not happy with these definitions:

```
Fehlbergamat = {{1/4}, {3/32, 9/32}, {1932/2197, -7200/2197, 
    7296/2197}, {439/216, -8, 3680/513, -845/4104}, {-8/27, 
    2, -3544/2565, 1859/4104, -11/40}};
Fehlbergbvec = {25/216, 0, 1408/2565, 2197/4104, -1/5, 0};
Fehlbergcvec = {1/4, 3/8, 12/13, 1, 1/2};
Fehlbergevec = {-1/360, 0, 128/4275, 2197/75240, -1/50, -2/55};
FehlbergCoefficients[4, p_] := 
  N[{Fehlbergamat, Fehlbergbvec, Fehlbergcvec, Fehlbergevec}, p];

Fehlberg45 = {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
   "Coefficients" -> FehlbergCoefficients, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4, 
   "EmbeddedDifferenceOrder" -> 5, "StiffnessTest" -> False};
sfehlberg45 = 
 NDSolve[{D[y[t], t] == -100 y[t] - 99 Exp[2 t], y[0] == 0}, 
  y, {t, 0, 0.5}, Method -> Fehlberg45]
CRK4[]["Step"[rhs_, h_, t_, x_, xp_]] := 
 Module[{k0, k1, k2, k3}, k0 = h xp;
  k1 = h rhs[t + h/2, x + k0/2];
  k2 = h rhs[t + h/2, x + k1/2];
  k3 = h rhs[t + h, x + k2];
  (k0 + 2 k1 + 2 k2 + k3)/6]
CRK4[___]["StepInput"] = {"Function"["Time", "DependentVariables"], 
   "TimeStep", "Time", "DependentVariables", "TemporalDerivatives"};
CRK4[___]["StepOutput"] = "DependentVariablesIncrement";
CRK4[___]["DifferenceOrder"] := 4;
CRK4[___]["StepMode"] := Fixed;
scrk4 = NDSolve[{D[y[t], t] == -100 y[t] - 99 Exp[2 t], y[0] == 0}, 
  y, {t, 0, 0.5}, Method -> CRK4]
```

And defining the residuals similar to documentations:

```
residual[t_] = D[y[t], t] + 100 y[t] + 99 Exp[2 t];
Plot[Evaluate[
  RealExponent[{residual[x] /. scrk4, 
  residual[x] /. sfehlberg45}]], {x, 0, 0.5}, 
  PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  PlotLegends -> {{"CRK4", "Fehlberg45"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually, I used the methods defined in the documents, I did not know it was necessary to put them here. However, I am confused about the image, as it stands, which method would say is the best fit or can be concluded to give the best approximation. I asked this because both graphs and numerical values are the same and I need residuals to be able to conclude which numerical technique is the best fit. I anticipate your response.

Comment: You can remove the `RealExponent` function and plot in log scale with '`LogPlot`. However, since residuals can be negative, in that case it would be better to define them as absolute value: `residual[t_] = Abs[D[y[t], t] + 100 y[t] + 99 Exp[2 t]]` and then `LogPlot[Evaluate[{residual[x] /. scrk4, 
   residual[x] /. sfehlberg45}], {x, 0, 0.5}, 
 PlotStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], RGBColor[1, 0, 0]}, 
 PlotLegends -> {{"CRK4", "Fehlberg45"}}]`.

Comment: Based on these results CRK4 is better because it has residuals with magnitude in orders of less than ~10^-9  whereas Fehlberg45 has residuals with magnitude in orders of less than ~10^-4.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity, you just confirmed my conclusions. If you don't mind, please can you send me a mail so we can collaborate or for possible collaborations? gracespeakss@gmail.com